parse field (possibly using regex) in mysql when selecting
I have a MySQL (MySQL v8) table where one column has a long string of information, but when I select it, I need to retrieve only a specific part of the long string.
I need as part of the response the value that comes immediately before the " - " part, and after the <Br> part (unless the beginning of the string, in which case there is no <Br>)
create table codes (
    id integer primary key
    desc text not null
);

insert into codes values (1, '423.9 - This is the first item<Br>511.9 - This is the second item<Br>486 - This is the third item (486.0 actually)<Br>42.a.7.31 - <Br>785.0 - 785.? unsure if decimal is correct')

insert into codes values (2, '428.0M - CHF NOS')

insert into codes values (3, 'E.423.9 - Just testing!<Br>511.9 - Another test 12345')

I need the part of the description immediately before the ' - ' part, for example after "select ... from codes" I would have this:
423.9, 511.9, 486, 42.a.7.31, 785.0
428.0M
E.423.9, 511.9


Why dont you normalise your data and create a separate table for what is in the description column? It would be so much easier to handle your data!

Agree with @Shadow ... this is an ugly cleanup operation, one which should have happened outside MySQL, before you inserted the data.  Regex could be part of the solution.

Ideally you should do this cleanup operation in some scripting language (e.g. Python, Perl) outside of MySQL, before you import your data into the database.  That being said, on MySQL 8+, we could try using REGEXP_REPLACE() for a regex option to extract out the terms wanted:
SELECT id, `desc`,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(`desc`, '([^ ]+).*?(<Br>|$)', '$1, '), ', $', '') AS output
FROM codes;

The regex pattern used here matches:

([^ ]+) match AND capture in $1 the first non whitespace term
.*? match until reaching the nearest
(<Br>|$) <Br> tag OR end of the string

Then, we replace with just $1 followed by commma and space, to build out the desired CSV string.  Note that the outer call to REGEXP_REPLACE is to strip off the final dangling comma.
Demo

Need to fixed regex expression. If I remove hypen(-) from second input. It still giving numeric data. Sample query: https://dbfiddle.uk/8-YogGjM @TimBiegeleisen
